# Apache log monitor inside a container

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I have a Nagios Log server installed on ubuntu 18.04. and I can access my ubuntu system logs as per documentation. Now I want to monitor apache error and access logs, which are in docker containers. Just wanted to know the process for same. I have done following inside docker container. But somehow I am not getting apache logs. Do I need to open port? or any other configuration required?

1. Installed rsyslog in docker container.
2. downloaded http://*.*.*.54/nagioslogserver/scripts/setup-linux.sh
3. bash setup-linux.sh -s *.*.*.54 -p 35544 -f "/var/log/apache2/error.log" -t apache_error

Comment: Just a advice, do not share your private IP address.

Comment: ok updated, i thought private IP are ok to share

Comment: What exactly does `setup-linux.sh` ?